# Регистронезависимость в implode

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$string = 'Шерсть хлопок шерсть 15 35 15';
$array = implode(' ', array_unique(preg_split('/\s+/iu', $string)));
echo $array;
```

Если данные в одном регистре, то скрипт работает, удаляет повторяющиеся значения. А если есть заглавные буквы, то нет, несмотря на флаг i. Как это исправить?

Comment: У пробельных символов нет регистра, так что им флаг i ничего не дает. А регистрозависимый у вас array_unique. Ну и implode тут вообще ни при чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приводим строку к нижнему регистру. По окончании возвращаем заглавную букву:

```
<?php
function mb_ucfirst($string)
{
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1)).mb_substr($string, 1);
}

$string = 'Шерсть хлопок шерсть 15 35 15';
$result = implode(
    ' ', 
    array_unique(
        preg_split('/\s+/iu', 
            mb_strtolower($string)
        )
    )
);

echo mb_ucfirst($result);
```

[PHP run and share online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a1a760cfaa7c6dff8000369cc1c5e7f8&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Суть ошибки из пояснения выше от @Alexey Ten стала ясна, но рабочий вариант я так пока и не мог создать. Надо думать, это самая лаконичная конструкция?